# issue when passing argument to a function with `myarguments...` in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, spine.js

i have a search model like this (got this from https://github.com/maccman/quora2)

```
Spine = require('spine')

classMethods = 
  query: (params) ->
    @select (rec) ->
      rec.query params

instanceMethods =
  query: (params) ->
    attributes = @query_atts?() || @attributes()
    for key of attributes
      value = attributes[key]
      if value?.query?(params).length
        return true
      else if value && typeof value == "string"
        value = value.toLowerCase()
        return true if value.indexOf(params) != -1
    return false

class Search extends Spine.Class
  @include Spine.Events

Search.Model = 
  extended: ->
    @extend  classMethods
    @include instanceMethods

Search.include
  init: (models...) ->
    console.log('models: ', models)
    @models  = models
    @results = []

  query: (params) ->
    @clear()
    return unless params
    @params = params.toLowerCase()
    @models.forEach (model) =>
      console.log(typeof(model))
      continue until typeof(model) == 'undefined'
      results  = model.query(@params)
      @results = @results.concat(results)

    @trigger "change"

  clear: ->
    @results = []
    @trigger "change"

  each: (callback) ->
    @results.forEach(callback)

module.exports = Search
```

and a Page model:

```
Spine = require('spine')

class Page extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'Page', 'title', 'description'

  @extend require('models/search').Model

  constructor: ->
    super

module.exports = Page
```

the issue i have is that whenever is instantiate a Search in my controller:

`Search.init(Page)` and log what init gets as arguments i have the Page as a first argument and then i have 4 undefined.

```
models:  [Page(title, description), undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

where do these come from? 
of course it works fine in quora and it would work fine if i would not use `models...` in the init.

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
Search.init
```

that invokes the `Module.init` method, [defined in Spine like so](https://github.com/maccman/spine/blob/master/src/spine.coffee#L538):

```
Module.init = Controller.init = Model.init = (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) ->
  new this(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
```

(Note that `Spine.Class` = `Module`.) That then invokes the `Search` constructor [inherited from `Module`](https://github.com/maccman/spine/blob/master/src/spine.coffee#L80), which forwards all those arguments to the `init` method that `Search.include` attached to the `Search` prototype:

```
constructor: ->
  @init?(arguments...)
```

Hence the four undefined arguments (originally `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, and `a4`).

Comment: that makes sense. so how should i implement it so that my init works as i actually expect? and what is of having 5 arguments defined in Module.init by default?

Comment: It seems to me that you should simply be using `new Search(Page)` rather than `Search.init(Page)`. If I understand correctly, the reason why calling `init` on the class is preferred is that you can override it and thus respond to instantiation at the class level; but you aren't doing this, so using `Search.init` does nothing but add noise.

Comment: the thing is that search is implemented as it is here https://github.com/maccman/quora2/blob/master/app/models/search.coffee#L26 and unless i modify how the Search model is initialized i can't pass the model directly to the class

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. The prototypal `init` is called from the constructor, so that's still going to happen if you use `new Search(Page)`.

Comment: so i have to say im not a js guru so everything i could not be right. i tried to pass in Page directly but that did not work but i might do something wrong...